Databricks Azure SQL Merge - issue with % sign in column name
When I am using databricks sql merge to update target table I have issues with columns which contains: "%" percentage sign
Merge:
(
    target_table.alias("trg")
        .merge(df_bronze_delta.alias("src"), "src.key= trg.key")
        .whenMatchedUpdate(condition = "trg.key<> src.key", set = update_cols)
        .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
        .execute()
)

update_cols contains it too:
'column_%_name_A': 'src.column_%_name_A'

In source and target table I have column which looks:
column_%_name_A

And get error like below:
None pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: [DELTA_MERGE_UNRESOLVED_EXPRESSION] Cannot resolve src.column_ in UPDATE clause given columns ...., trg.`column_%_name_A`, .... src.`column_%_name_A`; line 1 pos 0  SQLSTATE: 39000 SQLSTATE: XXKST

% is fine as part of column naming in databricks, manual merge with list of columns working fine but generic one is failing.
Thanks!

The standard ISO SQL need to have SQL didrntiefiers (names of tables, columns, constraints...) compound only with simple letters from A to Z, figures from 0 to 9, the character undersore _, and must not begin by a figure nor be a SQL keyword (TABLE, SELECT, DATE, TYPE....).
All other illegal names must have delimiter...
The standard ISO SQL delimiter is the double quote. Single quote is used only for strings.
So, your column names :
'column_%_name_A': 'src.column_%_name_A'

Must be :
"column_%_name_A": "src.column_%_name_A"

Because % is an illegal SQL character...
